# How does USB take care of retransmissions?

Tags: usb

I'm trying to understand the USB protocol at the packet level. In particular, I'm interested in how USB handles retransmission of bulk transfers in case of an error. For reference:

https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb3.shtml
https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb4.shtml#Bulk

Let's discuss normal transmission from peripheral to host first: The host sends an IN token to the peripheral. The peripheral responds with a data packet. Then the host sends an ACK. Due to the ACK, the peripheral knows that the data was received correctly by the host and the next IN token will be answered with a new data packet by the peripheral.

Now consider that something goes wrong. Assume, that the data packet is corrupted. So the host discards the data packet and does not send an ACK. When the peripheral receives the next IN token, it simply sends the previous data packet again. Is that correct?

Now consider the more tricky case that the data packet arrives correctly at the host, however the ACK sent by the host is corrupted. So the host received the data correctly, but the peripheral doesn't know about it because the ACK was not received correctly. To the best of my knowledge, the ACK is never retransmitted by the host.

I believe that the next IN token sent by the host is answered with a retransmission of the data packet. However, how does the host tell that it is the same data package? I don't find an explanation anywhere.

Is it related to the fact that there are two PID values for data packets (DATA0 and DATA1)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is yes; the device only considers the bulk IN packet to be successfully sent if it gets an ACK packet.

And for your second question, you guessed it correctly: the data toggle bit switches between 0 and 1, so if the host gets the same data packet two times in a row, it can tell that the second one should be ignored since it will have the same data toggle value as the one before it.

For more information, see section 8.6, "Data Toggle Synchronization and Retry" in the USB 2.0 specification.